# How to make this kind of Layout in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, frontend

[image]

I have problem in placing image view at middle of two different Layout.
please help

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable using ConstraintLayout:
Please note the constraints of the ImageView.

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container_top" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/container_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container_top" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using constraint layout and fix the Image view to centre of the screen and then by using vertical bias adjust the image view to the centre of top view.

Take this example:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footerAd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-30dp"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.198" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```